# Erro ao inserir dados na tabela do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Estou tentando enviar dados para o `MySQL` , de um reserva de restaurante , mas ele somente funcionou na primeira vez e agora quando tento enviar não vai mais. Qual o possível erro no meu script?

Arquivo de Conexão com o `MySQL`:

```
 <?php

    session_start();
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $usuario = "root";
        $senha = "";
        $dbname = "sistema";

        //Criar a conexao

            error_reporting(0);
        $link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "sistema");
         if($link->connect_errno){
             echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
             exit();
         }  

?>
```

A Query e o Formulário:

```
 <?php

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $mesa=$_POST['mesa'];
        $nome=$_POST['nome'];
        $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
        $data=$_POST['data'];
        $hora=$_POST['hora'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO reservar(mesa,nome,telefone,data,hora) VALUES('$mesa','$nome','$telefone','$data','$hora')";
        $resultado_cadastro = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    }


        ?>

    <form method="post" action="http://localhost/peixaria/inicio2.php?btn=entrega"> 
<div class="reservations">
  <h1>Reservar:</h1>

         <p>Mesa: </p>
      <input type="text" name="mesa" class="form" required>  


      <p>Nome: </p>
      <input type="text" name="nome" class="form" required> 
      <p>Telefone: </p>

    <input type="text" name="telefone" class="form" required> 
        <p>Data: </p>
    <input type="date" name="data" class="form" required placeholder="dd/mm/jjjj"> 
       <p>Hora: </p>
    <input type="time" name="hora" class="form" required placeholder="14:30"> 

  <button type="submit" >enviar</button>
</div>

<div class="thankyou">
  <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>

</div>

<div id="dtBox"></div>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Edilson mesmo assim não funciona .

Comment: O formulário e o código PHP que capta os dados, estão no mesmo arquivo .php ?

Comment: sim está no mesmo arquivo  @AlissonAcioli

Comment: Ah, não li bem o código, o banco de dados já la estava, vou ver leio isso melhor, mas também estás a passar mal os valores na função `mysql_query`, deves colocar as palavras entre aspas duplas ou chavetas. De qualquer form a o teu script parece algo confuso, dá-me algum tempo e vejo isso melhor.

Comment: Consegue postar a estrutura da tabela para melhor análise?
Sugiro utilizar o comando `desc nome_tabela;` no phpmyadmin ou outro gerenciador que você utiliza.

Comment: @Maurivan já postei

Comment: Nenhuma mensagem de erro é exibida?

Comment: @JefersonLeonardo não exibe nada e nem envia , alias só enviou na primeira vez .

Comment: Veja que não está passando valor para o campo `id_reserva` e o mesmo não é `auto_increment`. Tens alguma trigger que faça este trabalho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns dos dados, estão mal formatados, desde que são recebidos do formulário, e outros são por má definição nos atributos da tabela `reservar`. Usando esse código aqui, você consegue resolver o problema:

```
<?php
session_start();
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "sistema";

$link = new mysqli ($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
if($link->connect_errno){
 echo "Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
 exit();
}  


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $mesa = $_POST['mesa'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['data']));
    $hora = date('H:m:s', strtotime($_POST['hora']));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO reservar (mesa,nome,telefone,data,hora) VALUES('{$mesa}','{$nome}','{$telefone}','{$data}','{$hora}')";
    if($resultado_cadastro = $link->query($sql)){
        print "dados cadastrados na tabela";
    } else {
        print "ocorreu um erro durante o cadastramento da informação";
    }
}    

?>
```

Você precisa também de mudar o tipo da campo `data` para `time` e não `timestamp`, porque o `timestamp` espera normalmente um formato bem mais complexo `Y-m-d H:i:s` que é uma mistura da data e da hora com respectivos segundos. Certifica-te também de que o campo `id_reserva` seja do tipo `auto_increment`.

> - alter table `reservar` modify `id_reservar` int(11) not null auto_increment;
> - alter table `reservar` modify `data` date;

Mas depois de mudares o tipo do campo `data` para time, deves antes reajustar os dados do formulário, para que se adequa a esse padrão.

> - $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['data']));
> - $hora = date('H:m:s', strtotime($_POST['hora']));

O resto são erros, de estruturação mesmo, porque no teu código são declaradas variáveis que não são sequer usadas - *sessão, $servidor, etc* - e em vez de ficares a misturar `procedure mysqli` com o `object oriented mysqli`, é mais fácil se escolhes um e usas simplesmente dessa forma.

Comment: Me parece que Ele está tentando inserir alguma data no campo `datach`, pois `data` tem por padrão `current_timestamp`. Realmente o código dele está confuso!

Comment: @Maurivan realmente.